# How can I get the equipment in Quest 28 "No Turning Back"?

Tags: half-minute-hero

In this quest, I found the item store in the west village, but I have not found a way to get from the village to the castle before I run out of time. And even if I could, whenever I get to the village I never have enough money to buy the equipment. What to I have to do to both buy the equipment and defeat the boss without running out of time?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

Quest 28: No Turning Back
Hero's Courage - Kill all of the rock enemies that appear on the screen
Hero's Spirit - Help the man in the West village by taking the letter to his wife.

Equipment
Time Shield - West village for 500g.

Strategy - All (not True Hero, but this quest sucks)
Grab an herb at the first town and dash North, dash through the Rock monster fight, then dash West, and up and around the corner to attack the Rock Monster to the West of the first one. Dash through the fight again, now dash South and around the corner to the West and head North. You'll run out of HP at some point so either flee the fights, or use the herb (this part varies greatly, using the herb can screw you over when you need to return to village 1, so playthrough a couple times to get the feel, or just get lucky). Stop at the West village and buy the Time Shield and talk to the man about the letter to his wife. Now, head outside and DIE. You'll be sent back to town 1 where you need to buy the Goddess Power-up and Head East and then North through the NE path to the next Rock Monster. Dash through him and Go NW to the town. Handing the letter to the wife will grant you 10s and a secret path to the castle. Head North to kill the last monster and get another 10s. Now ideally, you can chance your power-up running out and try the Evil Lord now, or rush through the cave behind the castle, get the power-up from the village the you were just head, and back through the cave to the castle (what I did, very quick fight that way)

---

from: [forum guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showpost.php?p=4343918&postcount=8)

Comment: It's good that you're putting in where you found it, but we try to ensure answers here on Arqade are more than just straight up copy and paste.  Is there anything else you can add yourself?

Comment: Sorry about that, was just trying to help.

Comment: Even with that source, it would really be better if you didn't just copy and paste verbatim text that someone else wrote.